# $L^p$ stochastic processes and boundedness

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I have been looking at a proof on page 299 of the following paper:

- Promel, D. J., and Scheffels, D. Stochastic volterra equations with
  Hölder diffusion coefficients. Stochastic Processes and their
  Applications, 3 (2023), 291–315.

While I think I understand most of the proof, there is an element which I do not quite grasp. I have tried to capture it in the following setting. Hopefully this is clear enough.

---

Le $T>0$ and  $p>2$. Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\in [0,T]},\mathbb{P})$ be some filtered probability space. Let further $X = (X_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$ and $Y = (Y_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$ be some $(\mathcal{F}_t)$-progressively measurable stochastic processes. Suppose further that $X$ is in $L^p(\Omega \times [0,T])$ and let $f:[0,T] \to \mathbb{R}$ be some continuous function.

Suppose that, for some $C>0$, we have that

$$\mathbb{E}\big[\lvert Y_t\rvert ^p\big] \leq C \bigg(1 + \lvert f(t) \rvert + \int_0^t\mathbb{E}\big[\lvert X_s\rvert ^p\big]ds,  \bigg),$$

holds for all $t\in[0,T]$.

Then

1. Is the map $t\to \mathbb{E}[\lvert Y_t\rvert ^p]$ bounded?

I would argue that yes, it is. Indeed for $t\in[0,T]$, we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}\big[\lvert Y_t\rvert ^p\big] & \leq C \bigg(1 + \lvert f(t) \rvert+ \int_0^t\mathbb{E}\big[\lvert X_s\rvert ^p\big]ds,  \bigg) \\
& \leq C \bigg(1 + \sup\lvert f(t) \rvert + \int_0^t\mathbb{E}\big[\lvert X_s\rvert ^p\big]ds,  \bigg) \\
& \leq C \bigg(1 + \sup\lvert f(t) \rvert + \int_0^T\mathbb{E}\big[\lvert X_s\rvert ^p\big]ds,  \bigg).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Since $X$ is in $L^p$, then there is some $M>0$, such that
$$\mathbb{E}\big[\lvert Y_t\rvert ^p\big]<M, \quad \hbox{for all $t\in[0,T]$}.$$

2. Is $Y$ in $L^p(\Omega \times [0,T])$ ?

I would argue that, by integrating on $[0,T]$ we obtain that $Y$ is in $L^p$.

Is my development correct?

In the paper the authors have that $X = Y$ and wish to use Grönwall's lemma to obtain some bound on $X$. However, they use a sequence of stopping times seemingly to ensure that $t\to \mathbb{E}[\lvert Y_t\rvert ^p]$ is bounded. If my development above is correct, then using the stopping times seems unnecessary.

Some help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, if my eyes do not deceive me, I think both 1. & 2. are correct, 1. implies 2. as well.

Comment: Thanks @LNT. Then unless stopping times were used for something else, for this particular result they can be done away with.